# How to extract weights from softmax layer?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have problem understanding the output shape of the weights' matrix in Keras.

I have a simple BiLSTM like the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=55, weights=[pretrained_weights])) 
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=embedding_size)))
model.add(Dense(5926, activation='softmax')) # number of classes

print(model.summary())

weights = model.layers[-1].get_weights()
print(weights)
print(len(weights))
print(weights[0][0].shape)
print(weights[0][0])

for e in zip(model.layers[-1].trainable_weights, model.layers[-1].get_weights()):
    print('Param %s:\n%s' % (e[0],e[1]))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0005),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train), epochs=100, validation_data=(np.array(X_val), np.array(y_val)))
```

If I print the shape of the last layers' weights, I get this:

```
Param <tf.Variable 'dense_14/kernel:0' shape=(200, 5926) dtype=float32_ref>:
```

so the shape is (200, 5926).

Which is the number of neurons in my network by the number of classes. I would like to find a way to extract the weights associated with each prediction, because then I need to update the weights matrix.

My test set is composed my 680 sentences, where I have 1 label per sentence. The predictions have the following shape:

```
predictions = model.predict(np.array(X_test))
# shape predictions = (680, 5926)
```

Is there a way to extract from the softmax layer the weights for each prediction (with shape=(680,5926)? Like:

```
predictions = [probability_class_1, probability_class_2,......, probability_class_5926] 
weights = [weight_class_1, weight_class_2, ......., weight_class_5926]
```

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean the weights for each prediction?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more clear. My input is the following: X_train: sentences where each word has been transformed to index, y_label: one single label per sentence, in this case the label corresponds to a verb (converted to index) since I am trying to only predict verbs. I want to restrict my vocabulary, so instead of having a model that has to pick a verb among 5925 others, I want, for each input sentence, to predict between for example 5 verbs that I choose.

Comment: I want to do this by performing pair-wise multiplication, setting the weights of all the verbs "I don't want to use" to 0 and multiplying the others by one, so that my network will then predict one of these last verbs. To do this, I have to access the weights that are connected to my predictions, but I don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a second input with the masks telling which verbs for which sentences and perform a simple elementwise multiplication:

```
sentenceInputs = Input((sentenceLength,))
desiredVerbs = Input((5926,))

sentenceOutputs = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size, input_length=55, weights=[pretrained_weights])(sentenceInputs)
sentenceOutputs = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=embedding_size))(sentenceOutputs)

sentenceOuptuts = Dense(5926)(sentenceOutputs)
selectedOutputs = Multiply()([sentenceOutputs, desiredVerbs])
selectedOutputs = Activation('softmax')(selectedOutputs)

model = Model([sentenceInputs,desiredVerbs], selectedOutputs)
```

Now, create an array with the desired verbs:

```
desired = np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], 5926))

#for each sentence, make the desired verbs be one:
desired[sentenceIndex, verbIndex] = 1.

#now, how you're going to do this is up to you

#if they're the same for all sentences:
verbs = [selectedVerbIndex1, selectedVerbIndex2, ...... ]
for verbIndex in verbs:
    desired[:, verbIndex] = 1.
```

And fit with both inputs:

```
model.fit([np.array(X_train), desired], np.array(y_train), ......)
```

---

### Using the `class_weight` parameter in `fit`:

You can try to use your original model (not following the suggestion above) and use the parameter `class_weight` in the `fit` method.

This will be a little different, though. You won't be able to select the verbs when predicting, only when training. You won't be able to select different verbs for different sentences. The other verbs will never get any trained (maybe a model with `Dense(5)` would be more interesting?)

I'm also not very sure if you can have zero weights here.

```
verbWeights = { i: 0. for i in range(5926) }

desiredVerbs = [verbIndex1, verbIndex2, .... ]
for verb in desiredVerbs:
    verbWeights[verb] = 1.

model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight = desiredVerbs, ....)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very helpful!

Comment: :) -- Welcome to Stackoverflow -- When you consider an answer is satisfactory, please mark it as answered so you can flag to everyone that this is valid.

Comment: Sorry, I have another question. In the first example you are using Multiply(), but it gives me an error because the two arrays have different shapes. Is that necessary to use? Can I use something else?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? And the shapes of both inputs?

Comment: I managed to solve that error, but actually I realized that with this method I cannot extract the weights I need. Because what I am looking for is a way to extract the weights connected to the outputs predictions.

Comment: You already extracted the weights as you described in your question. I can't understand what you want. There isn't such a thing as "weights for each prediction", unless you're talking about adding these weights yourself because you want some samples or classes to be more significant in training.

Comment: Yes, this is what I think I a looking for. The idea is: right now, my network is predicting verbs and the number of possible verbs that could be predicted is 5926. I would like to restrict this number, so if the label is "eating", I want to assign a biggest value to some of the verbs and 0 to other ones, and I want to do it by pairwise multiplication, so if my label is "eat" and the verbs I want to predict from are ["eat", "drink", "sip"], I need to extract the weights from the softmax, multiply those by 1, if the verb is one of the previously mentioned, or 0, if the verb is anything else.

Comment: The idea is that my program then will be able to predict only among 3 verbs and not 5926! I hope this was clearer..sorry if I could not explain better before!

Comment: This is exactly what my answer is doing.